# remove class in angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an ionic app and I am running into some css troubles with a list item in ng-Repeat. I am creating a list view that is a bit customised for the first element using `ng-class='{large:$first}'`which makes the first thumbnail list item full size. Now testing this on an s6 hasnt brought about any problems but testing on an s4 mini reveals my mistake in that the image squashes itself into thumnail size regardless of my custom css. my list looks like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="World">
  <ion-content>
  <ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-class='{in:$first}' class="item-remove-animate item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right wrap" ng-repeat="world in worlds" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/app/world/{{world.id}}">
        <img ng-src="http://saharasystems.co.za{{world.imageLarge}}">
        <h2 ng-bind-html="world.title"></h2>
        <p ng-bind-html="world.created"></p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

is there a way, similar to adding a class to the first item in ng-repeat, to remove a class, i.e. remove `item-thumbnail-left`so that it does not interfere with how I want my first item displayed?

Comment: Yeah basicly the same way you are adding a class on the first item with ng-class. ng-class can conditionally add/remove a class. So you just have to create a condition that validates to true/false accordingly, removing/adding the class you want when the condition is true/false.

Comment: I am still quite new to angular and I am still quite fuzzy on how it works. how would I go about doing something like that. I cant seem to find anything in the documentation that can help

Comment: Check andras Endre's answer, his answer applies if you want only the first item to have the class `item-thumbnail-left`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case I would apply a css rule in all cases when the repeated item is not the first:

```
<ion-item ng-class="{'in':$first,'item-thumbnail-left': !$first}">
   ...
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it correctly but you need to set a `false` parameter to apply the class only when not the first item is listed.

`ng-class="{'in':$first,'item-thumbnail-left': !$first}"`

Doing `!$first` you are telling AngularJS to apply `item-thumbnail-left` class when the iteration is whatever but the first element.

Try it yourself. We are telling AngularJS to apply the `red` style to everything but the first box and `blue` to the first one.

```js
function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.products = [1,2,3,4];
}
```

```css
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
.box {
    width:80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-app>
    <div ng-repeat="p in products">
        <div ng-class="{'blue':$first,'red': !$first}" class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ng-show or ng-hide directives in combination with the scope. Something like:

```
ng-show="firstItem == 'someValue'"
```

where the `firstItem` is a global scope declared on angular controller part. There you can define the logic what should happen with the first item. Suppose you get the first item from collection, then you can assign a specific value for that scope.

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: He doesn't want to show/hide an element, but just add/remove a class from specific items in ng-repeat